# make init() private for NSObject subclass

Tags: swift

the class `FooClass` should only allow interaction via its `sharedInstance`. i am trying to prevent misuse by not allowing anyone to access `init()` of `FooClass`.

i have tried a few different approaches, but none work:

**Using private keyword:**

```
class FooClass: NSObject {
    // singleton
    static let sharedInstance = FooClass()

    let value: String

    private override init() {
        self.value = "asdf"
    }
}

// this should be a compile error, but it is not
let foo = FooClass()
```

**Using @available:**

```
class FooClass: NSObject {
    // singleton
    // COMPILE ERROR - "init is unavailable. use sharedInstance"
    static let sharedInstance = FooClass()

    let value: String

    @available(*, unavailable, message="use sharedInstance")
    override init() {
        self.value = "asdf"
    }
}

// COMPILE ERROR - as it should be
let foo = FooClass()
```

i have tried using internal as well, but still no luck.

**UPDATE**

first version works if you move it to its own file, however the ObjC version of the class still allows for init to be called. Any ideas?

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC11SwiftToObjC8FooClass")
@interface FooClass : NSObject
+ (FooClass * __nonnull)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * __nonnull value;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer addresses Swift 2. In Swift 3 it looks like the access level of a method is correctly imported from Swift to Objective-C and does not need to be marked as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` in order to disallow it from being available. Of course, there is no `new` method in Swift so that will still need to be marked as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` to maintain the singleton properly.

---

Your first approach will work as long as the class is put in its own file. The access control keyword `private` means that the defined feature will only be available within the containing file.

However, as you said, using the Swift class in Objective-C will remove the protection that `private` gives you. I believe that's because anything marked `private` will not have an entry in the imported header file generated by the compiler. Thus the `init` function inherited from `NSObject` is available because it isn't overridden.

The solution I found is to create another header file that explicitly declares an `init` function that can't be called.

Swift class:

```
@objc(FooClass)
class FooClass: NSObject {
  // singleton
  static let sharedInstance = FooClass()

  let value: String

  private override init() {
    self.value = "asdf"
  }
}
```

Objective-C header:

```
@interface FooClass (SharedInstance)
+ (instancetype) new  NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype) init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

You have to also block `new` because if you don't then an instance of the class could be created through it.

Testing:

```
FooClass* foo  = [FooClass sharedInstance]; // All good here
FooClass* foo2 = [[FooClass alloc] init];   // 'init' is unavailable
FooClass* foo3 = [FooClass new];            // 'new' is unavailable
```

I have a rudimentary example project here: [SharedInstance project git](https://bitbucket.org/kenbruno2/sharedinstance)

Comment: of course i realized this right as you answered! that is exactly right.

Comment: TL;DR: use the first implementation, but move it to its own file

Comment: the one issue w/ this is that the ObjC version of this class will still allow you to use init. know how to stop that?

Comment: Yep, it looks like you said. I tried it in a mixed Swift/Objective-C project and the `private init()` didn't matter for Objective-C code. No idea on how to fix that side of it, it works fine on the Swift side.

Comment: You can add this into the generated header "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h" under the class `@interface`: `- (_Nonnull instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;` I can't find out how to get that generated automatically.

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option due to it constantly being regenerated.

Comment: Right, although you could do your own self-generated version. Still, it's far from optimal.

Comment: the project has many swift files in it, if any of them are touched the generated header is modified. would probably need a build script or something

Comment: I think I have an acceptable solution to both problems, I updated the answer to show how it's done.

Comment: @ColGraff would you mind creating a sample project? Your solution sounds promising but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @benrudhart I added a link to one at the end of my answer

Comment: Thank you for helping out with the example project @ColGraff. Unfortunately this solution doesn't really help bc. I'm building a framework that has to export a properly generated swift header file. Furthermore your solution works only if the user imports the header that extends/ overrides the initializers of FooClass. In case one forgets to import it these initializers are still available.

Comment: Hi @ColGraff, could you update your answer regarding the definition of `private`? Since Swift 3, what you said is the definition of `fileprivate` actually. Thanks :)

Comment: @Gobe I believe this question is mostly moot for Swift 3 and up since it now looks like the access level for a method is respected when imported from Swift to Objective-C. The `new` method will still need to be marked as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` since there is no direct equivalent in Swift. I’ll look at adding a Swift 3 edit to the answer but I’d regard the question as mainly obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `@available()` annotation:

```
@available(*, unavailable, message: "Use __your_init__ instead")
override init() {
    fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer for Swift 4+ - thanks! It's odd that you have to have the fatalError() or it won't build, even though the macro makes init unavailable. Anyway, compile time errors are good! It flagged a test case that was missed when I didn't have the @available macro!

Comment: how can you assign an instance of the class to the sharedInstance variable with this approach?