# Is there a way to access callback in a function, from an extension of the class?

Tags: swift, react-native-native-module

In react native, I'm using NativeModules and RCTResponseSenderBlock to create a callback. Because the callback is specific to the function I declare in my bridge, I can't access it from the Extension that provides the feedback I need. This is built on the example code from the Mapbox Navigation iOS SDK.

I've tried various ways to reach the callback property from by extended class.

```
@objc(TbtNavigation)
class TbtNavigation: NSObject {
  @objc
  func takeMeToWH(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9131752, longitude: -77.0324047), name: "Mapbox")
    let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.8977, longitude: -77.0365), name: "White House")
    let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination])
    Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
      guard let route = routes?.first else { return }
      let navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)
      navigationViewController.delegate = self
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
      appDelegate!.window!!.rootViewController!.present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    callback(["CALLBACK WORKS HERE"])
  }
}

extension TbtNavigation: NavigationViewControllerDelegate {
  // Show an alert when arriving at the waypoint and wait until the user to start next leg.

  func navigationViewControllerDidDismiss(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, byCanceling canceled: Bool) {
    print("cancelled")
    callback(["I NEED THE CALLBACK TO WORK HERE"])
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    appDelegate!.window!!.rootViewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

callback in navigationViewController is 'unresolved identifier'

EDIT: the solution was to declare the callback variable in scope of the class.

```
@objc(TbtNavigation)
class TbtNavigation: NSObject {
  var callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock?

  @objc
  func takeMeToWH(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9131752, longitude: -77.0324047), name: "Mapbox")
    let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.912605, longitude: -77.035402), name: "White House")
    let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination])
    Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
      guard let route = routes?.first else { return }
      let navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)
      navigationViewController.delegate = self
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
      appDelegate!.window!!.rootViewController!.present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.callback = callback
  }
}
extension TbtNavigation: NavigationViewControllerDelegate {
  // Show an alert when arriving at the waypoint and wait until the user to start next leg.

  func navigationViewControllerDidDismiss(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, byCanceling canceled: Bool) {
    self.callback?([canceled])
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    appDelegate!.window!!.rootViewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: if you make `class TbtNavigation: NSObject` a singleton, and call `TbtNavigation.shared.callbackMethod()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35167535/1244597

Comment: thanks @AamirR. I think i understand what you're saying, but the callback is inside of my function. so i have.. `static let sharedInstance = TbtNavigation()` and then my function inside the main class is `func takeMeToWH(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {}`. inside that function i call `callback(["status"])` to trigger the callback. How do I do that within TbtNavigation.sharedInstace.takeMeToWH() ?